# Cypress custom command wont return value

Tags: cypress

I have a function that I want to add as a command so i can reuse it.

Its on cypress/support/commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("generatePassword", () => {

    return 'randomstring';
  }
);
```

Then on my test I want to use it as:

```
  it("Visits page", () => {

    const password = generatePassword();
    cy.log({password})
    // Here it logs this:
    //{password: {chainerid: chainer146, firstcall: false}}



  });
```

Any idea on how to get the actual value? Now i get this:

```
{chainerid: chainer146, firstcall: false}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use a custom command in this situation, use a simple function.

Comment: but I cant import files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically cypress works in promise chain and you're returning the promise chainerid from your custom command. You have to chain it to use in next statement. Use something like below.

```
it("Visits page", () => {
return cy.generatePassword().then(pwd => {
    cy.log(pwd);
  });
});
```